# VLookup(""All"",range,2,false) - What is ""all""?

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I'm working through some VBA code written by someone no longer with my organization.  In a DoWhile loop, the follow code is used for error handling:

```
    Do While x<=y
         If IsError(Cells(x,4) Then
              Cells(x,4).FormulaR1C1 = "vlookup(""all"", RangeName,2,false)"
         End If
```

I've never seen a vlookup reference "all" for the range and I can't find a named range in the code named "All".  Any insight or suggestion would be much appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: First step is to use the manual to determine the meaning of functions. If you're already in the VB editor you can use Intellisense to see directly what the function is looking for, just by positioning your cursor inside the first bracket of the function

Answer (score 0):

"all" is the value that is being looked up. `RangeName` would be the name of a named range, 2 is the second column, and `false` means take an exact match.

The syntax is (from [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1))

> VLOOKUP (lookup_value, table_array, col_index_num, [range_lookup])